# Is there anyway to rotate image -90 degree

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rotation

I am using rotateflip to rotate image and also save on server
here is the code:

```
using (Image image = Image.FromFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Job_Files/" + Job_ID + "/" + new_str + "/Images/" + path)))
{
    //rotate the picture by 90 degrees and re-save the picture as a Jpeg
    if (cbox_id == "cboxRight")
    {
        image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
    }
    else
    {
        image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
    }
    image.Save(new_path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    image.Dispose();
}
```

Image is rotated at right side on click of rotate right but not working on left rotate..how to rotate it??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both forks of your `if` statement contain the line:

```
image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
```

so, unless there's some serious magic going on, they'll both do exactly the same thing.

One of them should *probably* be:

```
image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
```

(rotation is *always* clockwise, so rotating `270` is identical to rotating `-90`).

Comment: I know I was trying by different options..is there any way

Comment: @debin, see the final code snippet, rotating 90 counterclockwise is the same as rotating 270 clockwise.

Answer (score 1):

***Rotating 270 degrees clockwise is the same as rotating 90 degrees*** ***anticlockwise***. so Use `RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipX`or `RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone`

***Update***: The provided options may be used as required.

Comment: Again, I have to ask: why would you flip when all you want is a simple rotation?

Comment: I have added FlipNone ... It depends on the OP that's y I gave both the options.... And Specifically I can Update to Flip None

Comment: Okay, I thought I may have been missing something since the question seemed to not mention flipping. If you're just providing it as an option, I guess that's okay.

Answer (score 0):

Try `RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipX` instead of `RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone` to rotate image left.

Comment: I wont rotate image to left

Comment: Why would you flip x afterwards?

Comment: After rotation on 270 degrees image will be located upside down therefore Flip option must be used. Maybe not `RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipX` but `RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipY`.

Comment: 270 degrees wouldn't be upside down, 180 would. And, if your intent is to then right the image (reflect on the horizontal center line), that is the same as reflecting on the vertical center line without an initial rotation. In which case, it's probably faster to do it in one operation, RotateNonFlip[XY] (whatever axis it is, I'm not sure off the top of my head).